# iOS:Screen is not updating its size after changing portrait to landscape and vice-versa orientation in iOS (iPad, iPhone) using Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, screen-orientation

**Packages **
-Xamarin.Forms(5.0.0.2291)
-Xamarin.Community.Toolkit(2.0.4)

**Controls**

- xct:TabView

**Expected Behavior**
-xct:Tabview items should automatically update its layout to match the device orientation changes.
-When orientation is changed from portrait to landscape (or vise versa) height and width of its child controls  should automatically be adjusted.

**Actual behavior -for android app**: Working as expected.

**Expected behavior -for iOS app**: xct:Tabview Item does not update width and height when switching orientation between portrait and landscape  when we rotate the device, the tab view is  messed up . Also contents of multiple tabs are overlapped.

***Following are the links for images***

[Landscape Mode View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0jS3.png)

[Portrait Mode View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx1oy.png)

***Note**: This problematic  behavior is for all the TabViews Page  in the Project

**What we tried?**
-We have Handled Orientation Changes in  OnSizeAllocated event on the tab page's.
-We have used SizeChanged method, which is rising when we are rotating device.
-In size change event we tried ‘ForceLayout’ method  but it didn’t help
-In the iOS project settings’,  Info.plist file we have check Supported interface orientations (iPad) and Supported interface orientations (iPhone) keys.

We were expecting when orientation is change from Portrait to Landscape xct:Tabview items should automatically update its layout to match the device orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on GitHub: [iOS: Tabview Item does not update width when switching orientation between portrait and landscape](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1294).

And from [the bijington commented](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1294#issuecomment-1021902153), the underlying CarouselView control might be causing this issue and there is no plan to fix this issue very soon. You may try his [suggestions](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1294#issuecomment-1121302420) and keep following up this issue.